# Magento 2 - Validate input number and allow only two digits after decimal point and submit form via AJAX

Tags: magento2, jquery, validation, form-validation

**Code Snippet**

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" name="vendor" method="POST" id="vendor" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="well">
        <strong><?php echo __('Enter Height:')?></strong>
        <input type="text"
               id="height" 
               name="height"
               placeholder="Please enter numeric value only"
               data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}" class="input-text form-control input-md">
            <button type="submit" class="action primary" id="calculateTotalSubmit" name="calculate-total-submit"><?php echo __('Calculate Total')?></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have given input value required true and validate-number, although it is validating `required field` input before form is post, it is not validating the `required number` and showing validation message after form is post. How could I add below validations using Magento 2 form validation rules

As you can see in image, it shows number validation message but form is also submitted.

[image: Number]

Using this script to submit form via ajax, validation is not working

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("#form-id").submit(function(){
            var height = jQuery("input[name='height']").val();
            var url = "MYURL";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {height:height},
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#result-data").html(response.output);
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

- Before form post, validate-number and allow only two digits after
  decimal point before form is submitted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pattern for validate by your own regular expression:

```
data-validate="{'required':true, 'pattern':/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/, 'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
```

You can check validate form using **.valid()** method:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        $(function() {
            $('#form-id').submit(function() {
                if($('#form-id').valid()) {
                    ... ajax query ...
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with jquery script being used to submit form via ajax. Your regex works fine but it does not validate if I use with this script. How do I check if data-validate true before form submit ?

Comment: I edited my answer, check please

Comment: Works like charm. Could you explain the usage of `valid()` and why do we have to use it ? Also how could I allow more than two decimal points by changing regex pattern ?

Comment: Magento validation widget `lib/web/mage/validation.js` use jquery plugin `lib/jquery/jquery.validate.js` for work. You can see all plugin's methods at https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-plugin-methods

Comment: Regex `/^\d+(\.\d{1,})?$/` must allow one and more digits after decimal point

Answer (score 0):

You can add this js function in your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveForm()
{
    var dataForm = jQuery('#vendor');
    dataForm.mage('validation');
    if (jQuery('#vendor').valid()) {
         jQuery('#calculateTotalSubmit').attr('disabled',true);
         jQuery('#vendor').submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

you also need to change your button code like below

```
<button class="action primary" onclick="saveForm()" id="calculateTotalSubmit" name="calculate-total-submit"><?php echo __('Calculate Total')?></button>
```

Comment: I have already used ` data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}'` default Magento validation classes. How could I achieve without using external jQuery script ?

Comment: you have to add this syntax  for validation var dataForm = jQuery('#vendor');    dataForm.mage('validation'); its default functionality you can refer this blog https://www.mageplaza.com/how-to-validate-form-magento-2.html